# Updating d3 scatterplot, new data points are not in the correct positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, scatter-plot

Spent hours on this and still not really sure whats going wrong.

My plot is supposed to update based on a bunch of parameters the user selects. When the plot needs to add new data points the new points are not displayed correctly on the plot.

Check out the new plot:

[image: Check out the new plot here]

With these parameters all the circles should be in a line. While the original "line" is in the correct location the new "line" does not match up with the grid.

Here is the function to make a new plot. This works fine, all the data points are where they should be.

```
export const newPlot = (Params) => {
  d3.selectAll("svg").remove();

  let margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  let x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
  let y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


  let svg = d3.select('.plot').append("svg")
      .attr('class', 'svgPlot')
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    d3.json(`../assets/data/${Params.type}${Params.Year}.json`, (error, data) => {
      if (error) throw error;

      const refinedData = parametrize(data, Params);
      refinedData.forEach((d) => {
        d[Params.xSelect] = Number(d[Params.xSelect]);
        d[Params.ySelect] = Number(d[Params.ySelect]);
      });

      let min = d3.min(refinedData,(d) => d[Params.xSelect]);
      x.domain([(min - 2 <= 0 ? 0 : min - 2),
                d3.max(refinedData,(d) => d[Params.xSelect])]);
      y.domain([0, d3.max(refinedData,(d) => d[Params.ySelect])]);


      svg.selectAll("circles")
        .data(refinedData)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr('id', (d) => `${d.Player}`)
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", (d) =>  x((d[Params.xSelect])) )
        .attr("cy", (d) => y((d[Params.ySelect])) );



      svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "x-axis")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .call(d3.axisBottom(x));


     svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "y-axis")
         .call(d3.axisLeft(y));


      svg.append('text')
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr('id', 'xlabel')
      .attr("transform","translate(" + (width - 20) + " ," + (height-5) + ")")
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(`${Params.xSelect}`);

      svg.append('text')
        .attr("class", "label")
        .attr('id', 'ylabel')
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 1)
        .attr("x", (height/2 - 250))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(`${Params.ySelect}`);
      });

};
```

Here is the update function. Circles that are added are not in the correct location and are all offset by the same amount.

```
export const rePlot = (Params) => {

  let margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  let xUp = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
  let yUp = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

  let tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "toolTip")
        .style("display", "none");

  let svg = d3.select('.svgPlot');

  d3.json(`../assets/data/${Params.type}${Params.Year}.json`, (error, data) => {
    if (error) throw error;

    const refinedData = parametrize(data, Params);

    refinedData.forEach((d) => {
      d[Params.xSelect] = Number(d[Params.xSelect]);
      d[Params.ySelect] = Number(d[Params.ySelect]);
    });

    let min = d3.min(refinedData,(d) => d[Params.xSelect]);
    xUp.domain([(min - 2 <= 0 ? 0 : min - 2),
              d3.max(refinedData,(d) => d[Params.xSelect])]);
    yUp.domain([0, d3.max(refinedData,(d) => d[Params.ySelect])]);

    svg.select('.x-axis')
       .transition()
       .duration(1000)
       .call(d3.axisBottom(xUp));


    svg.select('.y-axis')
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
       .call(d3.axisLeft(yUp));


    svg.select('#xlabel')
    .text(`${Params.xSelect}`);

    svg.select('#ylabel')
      .text(`${Params.ySelect}`);


    let circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
                    .data(refinedData);


    circle.exit()
          .transition()
          .remove();

    circle.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("cx", (d) =>  xUp((d[Params.xSelect])) )
      .attr("cy", (d) => yUp((d[Params.ySelect])) );


    circle.enter().append("circle")
        .attr('id', (d) => `${d.Player}`)
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", (d) => xUp((d[Params.xSelect])) )
        .attr("cy", (d) => yUp((d[Params.ySelect])) );

       });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first set of circles gets appended to a group that is translated:

```
let svg = d3.select('.plot').append("svg")
  .attr('class', 'svgPlot')
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

In this case, the `svg` variable refers to a translated group. However, when you later reselect, you actually append to the root SVG element:

```
  let svg = d3.select('.svgPlot');
```

This is the origin of the difference.